# difficulty with x , y coordinate

Tags: java

I am trying to solve one problem from Liang's book I have done most of it but I do not understand the part with the x and y coordinates.I have two classes TestRegularPolygon which is the driver class for RegularPolygon. The formula for the area is not currently correct I will deal with it later. I  am using eclipse the code is compiling and running if anyone can give me some idea how to do it I would appreciate it!

(Geometry: n-sided regular polygon) In an n-sided regular polygon all sides
have the same length and all angles have the same degree (i.e., the polygon is
both equilateral and equiangular). Design a class named RegularPolygon that
contains:

- A private int data field named n that defines the number of sides in the polygon
  with default value 3.
- A private double data field named side that stores the length of the side with
  default value 1.
- A private double data field named x that defines the x-coordinate of the center
  of the polygon with default value 0.
- A private double data field named y that defines the y-coordinate of the center
  of the polygon with default value 0.
- A no-arg constructor that creates a regular polygon with default values.
- A constructor that creates a regular polygon with the specified number of sides
  and length of side, centered at (0, 0).
- A constructor that creates a regular polygon with the specified number of sides,
  length of side, and x-and y-coordinates.
- The accessor and mutator methods for all data fields.
- The method getPerimeter() that returns the perimeter of the polygon.
- The method getArea() that returns the area of the polygon. The formula for
  computing the area of a regular polygon is

Draw the UML diagram for the class. Implement the class. Write a test program
that creates three RegularPolygon objects, created using the no-arg constructor,
using RegularPolygon(6, 4), and using RegularPolygon(10, 4, 5.6,
7.8). For each object, display its perimeter and area.

```
public class RegularPolygon 
{
    private int n; //number of sides of the polygon
    private double side; //store the length of the side
    private double x; // x coordinate
    private double y; //y coordinate

    RegularPolygon()
    {
        n = 3;
        side = 1;
        x = 0; 
        y = 0;
    }

    RegularPolygon(int n, double side)
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.side = side;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    RegularPolygon(int n, double side, double x, double y)
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.side = side;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setN(int then)
    {
        n = then;
    }

    public int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }

    public void setSide(double theside)
    {
        side = theside;
    }

    public double getSide()
    {
        return side;
    }

    public void setX(int thex)
    {
        x = thex;
    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(int they)
    {
        y = they;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return n * side;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return (n * side) * 5;
    }
}


public class TestRegularPolygon 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        RegularPolygon mypol = new RegularPolygon(6, 4);
        System.out.println("the area is: " + mypol.getArea() + " the perimeter is " + mypol.getPerimeter());

        RegularPolygon yourpol = new RegularPolygon(10, 4, 5.6, 7.8);
        System.out.println("the area is: " + yourpol.getArea() + " the perimeter is " + yourpol.getPerimeter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at all, this a task I am trying to do but there is no one to ask so ...

Comment: `RegularPolygon(int n, double side, double x, double y)` I think that already qualifies as an x-y-constructor.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `x` and ´y` coordinates specify the centre of the polygon, there's no more to it.

Comment: I thought we should use the x and y coordinate for positioning

Comment: First, you should work on the formatting of your question. Second you should be more precise with your question: Do you have problems understanding an algorithm? Don't you know how to implement an algorithm? etc. etc. Most of us might be hesitant to answer to a question where the problem is really vague and where someone just posts a list of requirements and a lot of code. The more precise you are the better and the more answers you'll get.

Comment: Cheers Thomas I am pretty new to this site and I do not have much experience in programming

Comment: What is your actual question? All you say in your problem description above is "it" and "the part with the x and y coordinates."  This suggests that you don't really understand the problem in the first place, which makes it hard for you to articulate a question about the problem, which makes it impossible for others to answer your question.

Comment: If you can't ask **specific** questions better than this, you are going to be pretty unsuccessful in telling a computer **specifically** what to do.

Comment: People, don't be too strict on him. He has done his code honestly, but doesn't understand what is it for. He has not so good teacher, obviously. Let us be better.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you re-read your question with the eyes of an outsider (with the benefit of a day's time, it'll be easier than you think) -- what _question_ do you want answered, specifically? It helps _us_ immensely if there is an actual question mark (`?`) somewhere in the question, to guide us to the one sentence that needs to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Area=n*side*side/4.0*cot(Pi/n);
```

Why do you need x and y for counting it?

I hope, you can manage the perimeter?

As for x, y, the problem is only psychological here. You have prepared the tools for their setting and getting, but you do not really use them. Image it as is your class will be used later for... drawing the polygon. Then you'll need these x,y.

Comment: You have them OK, as I see. What is the problem? (I put for you an upvote for not to be closed)

Comment: I do not know how the repesentation of x and y coordiante works

Comment: The problem is only psychological here. You set the x,y, but you do not really use them. Image it as is your class will be used later for... drawing the polygon. Then you'll need these x,y.

Comment: Cheers Gangnus I understand now. Thank you guys for your time I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Exercise89A {

private int n; //number of sides of the polygon
private double side; //store the length of the side
private double x; // x coordinate
private double y; //y coordinate

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise89A defaultpol = new Exercise89A();
    System.out.println("the area is: " + defaultpol.getArea() + " the perimeter is " + defaultpol.getPerimeter());

    Exercise89A mypol = new Exercise89A(6, 4);
    System.out.println("the area is: " + mypol.getArea() + " the perimeter is " + mypol.getPerimeter());

    Exercise89A yourpol = new Exercise89A(10, 4, 5.6, 7.8);
    System.out.println("the area is: " + yourpol.getArea() + " the perimeter is " + yourpol.getPerimeter());
}

Exercise89A() {
    n = 3;
    side = 1;
    x = 0; 
    y = 0;
}

Exercise89A(int n, double side){
    this.n = n;
    this.side = side;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Exercise89A(int n, double side, double x, double y){
    this.n = n;
    this.side = side;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void setN(int newn){
    n = newn;
}

public int getN(){
    return n;
}

public void setSide(double newside){
    side = newside;
}

public double getSide(){
    return side;
}

public void setX(int newx){
    x = newx;
}

public double getX(){
    return x;
}

public void setY(int newy){
    y = newy;
}

public double getY(){
    return y;
}

public double getPerimeter(){
    return n * side;
}

public double getArea(){
    double s2 = side * side;
    double pin = Math.PI/n;
    double tangent = Math.tan(pin);
    return (n*s2)/(4*tangent);
}    

}
```